# Not passing correctly the data

Tags: php, laravel

So I have a form which looks like this:

```
    @csrf

     <div class="row">
    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ implode('', $errors->all(':message')) }}</strong>
        </div>
    @endif
 </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="projectTitle">Project title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="proj_title" value="{{old('proj_title',$project->proj_title)}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="projectDesc">Description</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="proj_desc" value="{{old('proj_desc',$project->proj_desc)}}"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="clientId">Client Id</label>
        <select name="client_id" class="form-control">

            <option>1</option>

        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
    </div>
```

As you can see, user needs to input project title, project description and client id. 
Then I have an index page in which you can see the projects, and looks like this

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

@if (Auth::user()->role == 1)
    <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="/projects/create">Add Project</a>
@endif

<br><br>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Project Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Client Id</th>
            <th>Created by</th>
            <th>Created on</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody class="">
        @foreach ($project as $project)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$project->proj_id}}</td>
            <td>{{$project->proj_title}}</td>
            <td>{{$project->proj_desc}}</td>
            <td>{{$project->client_id}}</td>
            <td>{{$project->created_by}}</td>
            <td>{{$project->created_at}}</td>

        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>



@endsection
```

My intention is that it automatically gets the name of the user who is log in and puts it in the "created by" field, the code I made is this

```php
public function store(Request $r)
{

    $validatedData = $r->validate([
       'proj_title' => 'required|max:100',
       'client_id' => 'required',
       'proj_desc' => 'required',
    ]);

    $currentUser = Auth::user()->name;

    $r['created_by'] = $currentUser;


   (new Project($r->all()))->save();
   return redirect('/projects')->with('store','');
}
```

I tested returning the $r array and it has the correct name in the right index of the array, but i dont know why it doesnt get to the database.

Thanks in advance

Comment: might your `return redirect('/projects')->with('store','');` should show your newly created `project`?

Comment: Yes, but the thing is that it doesnt even get to the database

Comment: Do you have the fields in the Project model listed in the fillable array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First thing to do:

**Don't forget to correctly setup your model with:**

```php
/**
* The attributes that are mass assignable.
*
* @var array
*/
protected $fillable = [

];

/**
* The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
*
* @var string[]
*/
protected $hidden = [
];
```

your `created_by` field must be a foreign key to a `User` so you can achieve this by doing in your migration:

```php
$table->integer('created_by');
$table->foreign('created_by')
      ->references('id')
      ->on('users')
      ->onDelete('cascade')
      ->onUpdate('cascade');
```

Put in your `Project` model a `belongsTo` relationship:

```php
/**
* Get the user that owns the phone.
*/
public function creator()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**See:** [laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

### Second thing

**replace:**

```php
(new Project($r->all()))->save();
```

**by:**

```
$project = Project::create($r->all());
```

### Second step

**Change your return:**

```php
return redirect('/projects')->with('store','');
```

**by:**

```php
return redirect('/projects')->with(['project' => $project]);
```

### Third step

When you want to retrieve the project's creator do:

```php
<tr>
   <th>Created by: {{ $project->creator->name }}</th>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I did what you said above but when I submit the form i get 'Trying to get property 'name' of non-object' from     ```    <tr>
   <th>Created by: {{ $project->creator->name }}</th>
</tr>    ```   What can I do about this?

Comment: @Jesus try before the `return redirect('/projects')->with(['project' => $project]);` try to: `dd($project->creator()->first())`

Comment: try to `dd($project->creator())`